# Getting XDocument to recognize embedded SSML

Tags: c#, .net, ssml

I am using text to speech to add voice to a video tutorial. Currently all the text is in a file and is read into a C# application and parsed into multiple steps. What I would like to do is add ssml to the text file, specifically, the ability to  (pause) throughout a specific instruction.  I am using example code from [Cognitive-Speech-TTS](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-TTS). This code uses a nice clean approach of

```
private string GenerateSsml(string locale, string gender, string name, string text)
    {
        var ssmlDoc = new XDocument(
                          new XElement("speak",
                              new XAttribute("version", "1.0"),
                              new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "lang", "en-US"),
                              new XElement("voice",
                                  new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "lang", locale),
                                  new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "gender", gender),
                                  new XAttribute("name", name),
                                  text)));


        return ssmlDoc.ToString();
    }
```

As an example if I set "text" to be

```
string text = @"During this video we will refer to this as the lens, 
                <break time=""1000ms"" />  this as the headband  
                 <break time=""1000ms"" />, and these as the frame arms 
                <break time=""1000ms"" />. " };
Content = new StringContent(GenerateSsml(inputOptions.Locale, genderValue, inputOptions.VoiceName, text))
```

It will not recognize the embedded xml. Is there a way to get the XDocument to recognize the xml in text. Note that in the actual application text is being populated from a data file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in a string, so LINQ to XML thinks you want that to be a text node, escaping the text as appropriate.

It looks like you really want to include multiple nodes - some text, and some elements.

I'd suggest changing your `GenerateSsml` like this:

```
private string GenerateSsml(string locale, string gender, string name, IEnumerable<XNode> nodes)
{
    var ssmlDoc = new XDocument(
                      new XElement("speak",
                          new XAttribute("version", "1.0"),
                          new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "lang", "en-US"),
                          new XElement("voice",
                              new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "lang", locale),
                              new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "gender", gender),
                              new XAttribute("name", name),
                              nodes)));
    return ssmlDoc.ToString();
}
```

Then change your calling method to:

```
var nodes = new XNode[]
{
    new XText("During this video we will refer to this as the lens,"),
    new XElement("break", new XAttribute("time", "1000ms")),
    new XText(" this as the headband"),
    new XElement("break", new XAttribute("time", "1000ms")),
    new XText(", and these as the frame arms"),
    new XElement("break", new XAttribute("time", "1000ms"))
    new XText("."),
};
Content = new StringContent(
    GenerateSsml(inputOptions.Locale, genderValue, inputOptions.VoiceName, nodes));
```

If you really want to use the string representation instead, you *could* write:

```
string text = ...; // Code as before
var element = XElement.Parse($"<root>{text}</root>");
Content = new StringContent(
    GenerateSsml(inputOptions.Locale, genderValue, inputOptions.VoiceName, element.Nodes()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Both option in general would work. However, my goal is to be able to add the SSML markup into a text file with the script that way in the future when the script changes we will only need to modify the text file. It appears that I am going have to parse out the markup tags once I read in the file. My hope was something similar to using '@' was available to have the text read in as it.  Actually, looking at it again the second option may work. I tried this but did not add the <root> element so was getting an error.

Comment: @Doc: So just to clarify, is the second approach working for you, or are you still looking for something else?

Comment: I am actually working through the following error <br/><br/>System.Xml.XmlException
  Message=Name cannot begin with the '1' character, hexadecimal value 0x31. Line 1, position 74. <br/> <br/>The actual input string I am using is: <br/><br/> "Before picking up the HoloLens it is important to learn the no-touch zones. Avoid touching the lens. The lens should only touch soft surfaces. If you haven't already removed the HoloLens pause this video and do so now <break time="3000ms" />."

Comment: @Doc: Given that that string doesn't contain the character '1' anywhere, it sounds like the problem is elsewhere. I suggest you create a short but complete example, then put that into a new question.

Comment: I figured it out. I was reading a different line which had <break time=""1000ms"" />. The double quotes are not needed in this approach

Comment: Right, that would explain it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The second solution worked for my problem.  Now I can have people only update the text file without having the fiddle with the code.